# Item checkout on different orders at the same time for limited stock

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce

Having an issue where i have an Item in my inventory which has limited stock of 1. As soon as my mailer goes out people tend to buy at the exact same time.

The problem is when **User1** adds  the product to his cart, and **User2** adds to his cart then both User1 and User2 checkout at the exact same time it generates an order for both.It should pick-up there was 1 stock so only User1 should be able to checkout.

Just want to know how someone else wil handle this situation seen allot of people running into this bug.

any ideas ?

read some woocommerce solution: 
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12467

Comment: Well, when you actually go to place the order, you have to do so in a way that does not have any race conditions and one order for the limited item will succeed and one will fail and you can then advise that user that the item is out of stock.  Exactly how you code that depends upon your database design and how your code works, but the key is that you have a no-race-condition design and you are properly verifying stock when placing orders.

Comment: In general, you would want to be using transactions for processing the order (so you can back out the order if anything fails) and you'd want to be using an atomic database operation for decrementing the instock values so there are no race conditions on the decrement.  If any decrements fail (out of stock), you unwind the transaction and inform the user exactly what failed.  For education on the topic, read about "atomic database operations" that are not subject to race conditions.